# laravel access native php script

Tags: php, laravel, routes, require-once

I'm trying to run a native php script using laravel routes.php , view, controller. but no chance.

for example if i have a `test.php` inside views path and require it in a view blade:

```
 <?php
    require_once 'test.php';
 ?>
```

then build a route to that view and point to it:

```
 FatalErrorException in b012cb264e405ddcdbcd54b1275905692fac6df9.php line 26:
 main(): Failed opening required 'test.php' (include_path='.;E:\xampp\php\PEAR')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
require_once base_path('resources/views').'/test.php';
```

Or
This is in your config/view.php

```
require_once Config::get('view.paths').'/test.php';
```

Laravel 5+ (Global config)

```
require_once config('view.paths').'/test.php';
```

Comment: none of the methods works. by the way the third one is only for including blade not pure php file

Comment: @alex `require_once base_path('resources/views').'/test.php';` trye to add a slash

Comment: excellent .just add `/` to both example codes before `test.php`

Comment: Please update your answer with correct approach for future visitors of SO